# How to copy all properties of a class to a new subclass in Perl?

Tags: perl, class

```
my $t=TT::Pop->new(name => "shadowfax", color => "white");
my $w=TT::Pop::Subs->new($t);
```

How to write TT::Pop::Subs::new() so that I can make $w cantains all the properties from $t ?
In other words, I want to initialize a class with its super class.

In this case, all properties from $t should be readonly, so copy by ref is acceptable.
(I am not sure whether perl can make those properties readonly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't call your method `new` call it `promote` or something like that.

I have mixed feelings about how to handle this design.  My initial reaction is that you should use accessor methods and 'manually' copy the values into a new object.

```
sub promote {
    my $class = shift;
    my $obj   = shift;

    my %args = map { $_ => $obj->$_ } qw(
        attribute
        another
        this_one
        that_one
    );

    return $class->new( %args );
}
```

This insulates your subclass from changes in the parent.

Your parent class may now be or become an inside out object or something else that does not `clone` well.  A critical attribute in the parent may be replaced by a method that generates it from other attributes.

Obviously, a degree of coupling between a parent and child class is unavoidable.  But this approach helps minimize it.

The other way that seems obvious is to use a `clone` and rebless like jkramer suggests.  The big problem with this is that you have these restrictions:

- your parent class objects must be clonable
- your parent and child classes must implement storage in identically.
- accessor/mutator methods must not use a class-name prefix for attribute access.  This means that class Foo stores `attrib` in `$self->{'Foo::attrib'} = 'value';` while Foo::Bar stores them in `$self->{'Foo::Bar::attrib'} = 'value';`

For cloning, I would use `Storable`'s `dclone`.  It has the advantage of being a core module, and many more exotic object implementations provide hooks for Storable so that cloning will work properly.

Comment: It should be better to explicit which property to copy if I want to make the class more universal.
And your way looks more atomic.

Answer (score 2):

Use Clone to make a deep copy of your data structure and bless the new hash:

```
use Clone qw(clone);

my $w = bless clone($t), 'TT::Pop::Subs';
```

Or if you want to create a copy constructor in TT::Pop::Subs:

```
# In TT::Pop
use base 'Clone'; 

# In TT::Pop::Subs
sub new {
  my ($class, $source) = @_;
  return bless $source->clone, $class;
}
```

Read more about clone here: http://search.cpan.org/~rdf/Clone-0.31/Clone.pm
Of course there are many other modules that do the same thing (deep copies of data structures), just pick the one you like best.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub new {
    my $this = shift;
    my $class = ref($this) || $this;
    my $SuperClass = shift;
    my $self = ref($SuperClass)?{%$SuperClass,}:{};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Well, this makes a copy of the hash.

Comment: my $w=TT::Pop::Subs->new($t); 
So, scalar @_ == 2;